# github API - using curl PUT to add a repo to a team

Tags: curl, github, put

I am trying to add a repo to a team on github, thus:

```
curl -i -u username:password  -X PUT  -d "" https://api.github.com/teams/:team/repos/:user/:repo
```

(specifics left out)

Pretty much as indicated in the not so verbose documentation.
This gives a `500 Internal server error`.

If I leave out the `-d""` it gives a `411 "Content-Length required"`,
if I specify (using `-H`) `"Content-Length: 0"`: again the `500` error...
Any clues?

---

[edit] Answer: the API was giving spurious responses and the docs are not very good there:
"`:team`" is a numerical id assigned by the system (not the name you gave it .. arg!) - it is available only from an API query or from looking at the url in the browser when you visit the team.  How  elegant.
Moreover, it does not seem that you can assign just *any* ol' repo under your account - it must be in the "organization" to which the team belongs.
Getting it there will apparently require some entertaining gymnastics... more if I figure it out. GitHub Usablity rating so far: (1-10) 2.

---

[edit 2] The conclusion: the documents on github prescribe this:

> Add team repo
>
> In order to add a repo to a team, the authenticated user must be an owner of the org that the team is associated with.

```
PUT /teams/:id/repos/:user/:repo
```

Does not work.  What *does* work is this:

```
PUT /teams/:id/repos/:org/:repo
```

Replacing "`:user`" with "`:org`" (the name of the "organization" that the team belongs to.

Case closed. Hopefully this helps somebody avoid a similarly entertaining afternoon.

Comment: Very interesting. You can actually put your edit2 as an answer of its own in this same page.

Comment: Good point - then it would have shown up flagged as answered. Is there a "closed" or "solved" state? I'll put in a dummy answer ..

Comment: no need to put a dummy answer: you can cut and paste your edit2 part as an actual and real answer, and select your own answer as the official one. There isn't a "closed" state though, in that other reader can post their own answers if they think having a more effective way.

Comment: For anyone coming across this, make sure you have `-X PUT` in your `curl` command and not `-X put`... it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure that the :repo is the `repo["name"]` field, NOT the `repo["id"]` field.

Answer (score 1):

"The documents on github prescribe this:"

> Add team repo
>
> In order to add a repo to a team, the authenticated user must be an
> owner of the org that the team is associated with.

`PUT /teams/:id/repos/:user/:repo`

Does not work. What does work is this:

`PUT /teams/:id/repos/:org/:repo`

Replacing ":user" with ":org" (the name of the "organization" that the team belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this again... it looks like :org is now the full name and not the ID