# How do I PUT to the github API using curl?

Tags: curl, github-api

There are many github API examples. However, I haven't been able to discern how to PUT to github using cURL and the API. In particular, I'm trying to auto-follow a user.
I've tried:

```
curl --user "myusername:mypassword" -X PUT "/myusername/following/personIdliketofollow" https://api.github.com/
```

as well as:

```
curl --user "myusername:mypassword" -X PUT "" https://api.github.com/myusername/following/personIdliketofollow
```

And multiple combinations thereof. 
I've looked [here](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923405/github-api-using-curl-put-to-add-a-repo-to-a-team), and [here](https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/) among other [sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193577/how-do-i-make-use-of-the-github-api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh. It seems that posting a question is the best way to find the answer. I spent hours on this. I'll go ahead and post the answer to save others time. In order to use cURL to PUT to Github to follow another user the syntax is:

```
curl --user "username:password" -X PUT -d "" https://api.github.com/user/following/personYoudLiketoFollow
```